# Creating a Report on Donor History

Tags: civicontribute, reports

Good morning,

I need to look through our donors and see who is a recurring donor and who is not. What is the protocol to create these kinds of reports?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Install this extension:
https://github.com/adixon/ca.civicrm.contributionrecur

And it will create a report template (Reports -> Create Report from template) for you that you can use to get at all your recurring series data (frequency, installments, status, amount, next scheduled date and more).

For anyone using the iATS payments extension we include a report template very similar to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a search (slightly different from a report) by going to **Search menu > Advanced Search**.  From there, open the "Contributions" section (by clicking on the header) and then open the "Recurring Contributions" subsection.  Set your criteria and press "Search".

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about creating reports here: [What is CiviReport?](http://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/reporting/what-is-civireport/)

However, for this sort of question you may find the search functionality is more powerful. By using an advanced search you can filter your contacts by a range of different criteria to generate the information you need. Read more here: [Advanced Search](http://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/the-user-interface/searching/#advanced-search)